# *ngIf not detecting changes on variable change on swiper.js (slideChange) event but detects on swiperRef.slideTo(index ) call

Tags: javascript, angular, swiper.js

iam passing an array of object containing photo url to swiper container,
for unverified photo iam showing a a text,
on each slide change i have to check photos verification status
the variable is changing to true or false but dom is not updating even when i inspect it shows

```
    ng-reflect-ng-if :'true;
```

but i have to scroll to a specific slide on user clicking on specific thumbnail

for that iam using

```
this.photoPopupSlider.swiperRef.slideTo(RowIndex, sliderSpeed);
```

at this time onSlidChange event triggers updates the dom correctly

my component.html

```
    <div style="padding: 0">
        <swiper
          [config]="sliderConfig"
          class="sliderBox"
          [pagination]="false"
          (slideChange)="onSlideChange($event)"
          #photoPopupSlider
        >
          <ng-template swiperSlide *ngFor="let pic of myPhotos">
            <div
              class="slide_wrap"
              style="height: 68vh; background: #f3f4f9"
            >
              <img
                [src]="pic.image"
                class="slide_img"
                style="height: auto; width: auto; max-width: 100%"
              />
            </div>
          </ng-template>
        </swiper>
        <span
          id="photo_under_verification"
          *ngIf="underVerification"
          class="ph_uv"
          >Photo under verification</span
        >
      </div>
```

my component.ts file

```
    underVerification = false;
    onSlideChange([swiper]: any) {
      const index = swiper.activeIndex;
      this._ps.sliderIndex = index;
      this.sliderIndex = index;
      console.log("sliderChanged", this.sliderIndex);

      const photoShowingInSlider = this.myPhotos[index];
      const isPhotoUnderVerification =
        photoShowingInSlider?.photostatus == "0" ? true : false;
      this.underVerification = isPhotoUnderVerification;
      console.log("under", isPhotoUnderVerification);

       // const photUnderVerifyMsg = document.getElementById(
       //   "photo_under_verification"
       // ).style;

       // if (isPhotoUnderVerification) photUnderVerifyMsg.display = "inline";
       // else photUnderVerifyMsg.display = "none";
    }
```

actually i was able to implement the logic by using document.getElemntById

those commented lines of code ( i thing it is a bad way in angular to access dom that way )

how can implement this login in angular way ( means not accessing dom directly ) ?

Comment: Are you using `OnPush`? Make `this.underVerification` a behavior subject, then do `this.underVerification.next(photoShowingInSlider?.photostatus == "0")` in the component, and `*ngIf="underVerification | async"` in the template.

Comment: @Carcigenicate no iam not using OnPush. the photo is object i has 4 keys image,photostatus,. onSlideChange iam setting underVerification to true or false based on photostatus it is synchronous one.

Comment: @Carcigenicate i added like this

  underVerification = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

this.underVerification.next(isPhotoUnderVerification);and in html
*ngIf="underVerification | async". but the same result dom is not updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to tell Angular to run change detection as the code under `onSlideChange` (and other events) runs [outside of Zone](https://swiperjs.com/angular#swiper-component-events)

> Note that Swiper Angular component all events emits outside of NgZone
> for better perfomance. Dont forget to use `ngzone.run` or
> ChangeDetector if you need to change view (e.g slides) in event
> handlers (e.g `slideChange`).

import the ChangeDetectorRef in the constructor and call the detectChange method in `onSlideChange` method

```
this.cd.detectChanges()
```

Here is the working code. I just take a random stackblitz link so adapt to your swiper version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-angular-example-rmgv2b